# My alphabetical string organizer won't save into a file correctly

Tags: c++, fstream

I have a function that I want to take a file, look at the words in the file, position them in alphabetical order and replace the file with that. So far, I have it to get the words in alphabetical order. The problem is, is that it only saves the last word to the file. 
Here is my current code:

```
void thingy(string Item)
{
        fstream File;  // Open the file, save the sorted words in it, and then close it.
        File.open("Data/Alphabet.txt", ios::out | ios::in);
        File << Item;
        File.close();
}




void Alphabetical_Order(string Text_File)
{

fstream file;      
file.open(Text_File);         // Open the file that we are going to organize
std::set<std::string> sortedItems;  // The variable that we will store the sorted words in


fstream words;            // To see how many words are in the file
words.open(Text_File);
int Words = 0;
do
{
    string word;
    words >> word;
    Words++;
} while (!words.eof());




for (int i = 1; i <= Words; ++i)  // Set a loop to take the words out of the file and put them in our variable
{
    std::string Data;
    file >> Data;
    Data = Data + " ";
    sortedItems.insert(Data);
}





std::for_each(sortedItems.begin(), sortedItems.end(), thingy);
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Just a passing comment on the function `thingy`. The `fstream` constructor can open a file, without needing a separate call to `open`. When you do that, the default mode is `ios::out | ios::in`. And the destructor will close the file. So the function only needs two lines: `std::fstream File("Data/alphabet.txt"); File << Item;`. (yes, `std::fstream`; we don't need no stinking' `using namespace std;`)

Comment: That's because your fstream is at the end of the file.  You will have to reposition the stream in order to read it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open the `fstream` in `thingy`, try opening with `ios::ate` flag as well. This will allow you to append your text to the file, rather than rewrite every time you call the function.

That being said, you should not be opening and closing the file every time you call the function. Maybe pass a reference to a `fstream` that gets managed from outside the function `thingy`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This worked to save all the words to the file, and they are all in alphabetical order. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Aiden already pointed out the main problem in your code (+1).

For the records, I'd like however to propose you a more efficient output using the powerfull [`ostream_iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ostream_iterator/?kw=ostream_iterator): it avoids opening/closing the output file a lot of times and doesn't need trailing spaces in all strings. This being said, I'd suggest to void the unnecessary double pass read as well:

```
void Alphabetical_Order(string Text_File)
{
    ifstream file(Text_File);    // Open in read mode   
    std::string word;
    std::set<std::string> sortedItems;  // The variable that we will store the sorted words in

    while (file >> word) {       // just read the file in one pass 
        sortedItems.insert(word);    // to populate the set
    }

    ofstream ofs("alphasorted.txt");                                  
    std::copy(sortedItems.begin(), sortedItems.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(ofs, " "));
}
```